# How to clean up my parsing of an XML SOAP response

Tags: php

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetUsersResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetUsersResult xmlns:a="http://drivecam.com/Services/MessagesAPI" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:Users>
                    <a:UserSummary>
                        <a:EmployeeNum>1</a:EmployeeNum>
                        <a:FirstName>Bob</a:FirstName>
                        <a:LastName>Joe</a:LastName>
                        <a:UserId>1234</a:UserId>
                    </a:UserSummary>


function lytxGetDriverID($employeeNum) {
        $response = lytxGetUsers(lytxGetSessionID());
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadXML($response);
        $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('UserSummary');
        $userID = null;
        foreach($nodes as $node){
           foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
                if ($child->nodeName == 'a:EmployeeNum') {
                    if ($child->nodeValue == $employeeNum) {
                        $userID = $node->childNodes[3]->nodeValue;
                        break 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (is_null($userID)) {
            $userID = 'Not Found';
        }
        return $userID;
    }
```

I wrote some code using DOM to parse a SOAP XML response. I simply want to supply the function a employee number, and it returns the userid. My code works, but I feel like it could be better. I don't like the fact that I'm going after a hard coded index childNodes[3] in case there are more or less tags. Or just curious about a better way to parse this response. Thoughts?